# Card interaction: Basilisk and draw then discard.

Tags: harry-potter-hogwarts-battle

Was playing a round and had the Basilisk in play and trying to play an ally (can't remember which one off the top of my head) that says draw then discard.  Since Basilisk is out you can't draw but do you still have to discard to have it count as played for cards that have a secondary affect for playing an ally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [comprehensive FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/141111/hogwarts-battle-rules-clarifications-and-faq) compiled from answers to questions from the game designer

> Q: If a Villain blocks part of a card effect, can you or must you execute the rest of the action?
>
> A: Yes.  For example, Lockhart says “Draw one card, then discard any one card.”  If the Basilisk is in play and you choose to play Lockhart, you would not draw the card but you would still have to discard.  Neville could thus use Lockhart to discard his Remembrall to gain two influence.
> Source: https://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/24479506#24479506

Comment: Lockhart was the card I was thinking of but I don't own the game so I couldn't easily go check.  Thank you for the quick response.